# Push ViewController on Top of TabBarController

Tags: ios, authentication, uitabbarcontroller

I'm stuck on a problem I really don't know how to solve:

I have a TabBarController defined in my AppDelegate.

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

In this TabBarController i have several other NavigationControllers which have UiVieController inside:

```
ProgramController *programContr = [[ProgrammController alloc] init];
UINavigationController navControllerPro = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:programContr];

ManualController *manualContr = [[ManualController alloc] init];
UINavigationController navControllerMan = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:manualContr];
```

and i add the NavigationController to the TabBarController:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navControllerPro,navControllerMan, nil];
```

I set the tabBarController to the rootViewController:

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That works fine.
Now i want to add a "Login Screen" on top of that.
I did this with:

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:navControllerLogin animated:YES];
```

Now the TabBarController loads its content in the background even if the LoginViewController is in front. How to load the TabBarController only if a Button is pressed on the LoginViewController?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab bar controller is loaded everytime beacuse you set it as the rootViewController.

You should set a normal viewController as the root.. and if the login was succesfull the you should call the tabBarController to be loaded.

In other words, in the appDelegate there should be only the login window.. and in the loginViewController, if the login was ok, you should call and load your tabBarController with all its controller.. using storyboard makes it a lot easier.

Comment: but then i have to initalize the whole tabBarController with its subViewController in the loginController, right?

Comment: Right, its actualy a good practice to just load the views when its needed, this is called "lazy allocation".. your app will open faster.